# Maximize issue on dual monitor in Kubuntu 19.10

Tags: kubuntu, kde, 19.10, plasma, scaling

I have Kubuntu installation in a dual monitor setup (Intel HD graphics) and I have an issue where on screen one I have panel on top and latte-dock on the bottom, and when I want to maximize windows on screen 2 that has no panels it leaves the gap size of the panel on screen 1. Can this be fixed?

[image: both screens screenshot]